# Stats on images in questions

Tags: discussion, images

Do images in questions originate more from uploads or web links? Anyone have the stats on this?

Comment: Good luck querying http://data.stackexchange.com

Comment: Why do you want to know? I'm not criticizing, just curious.

Comment: @PopularDemand - I was just curious myself. I spend too much time on SO, and after editing a question today that had an image, I just wondered if one method was more popular than the other.

Answer (score 3):

Jan Dvorak [comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176297/stats-on-images-in-questions#comment529287_176297) that you could query the data.stackexchange.com but doing so would be rather tricky.

Consider the following post

```
Image with image Tag

<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXn07.png/">

Image with `![]`

![Image In Post][2]

[Link To the Image][3]



Back tics 
`<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXn07.png/">`

Part of code block

    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXn07.png/">


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXn07.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXn07.png
```

Which renders as

---

Image with image Tag

[image]

Image with `![]`

[image: Image In Post]

[Link To the Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXn07.png)

Back tics 
`<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXn07.png/">`

Part of code block

```
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXn07.png/">
```

---

Note that string `https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXn07.png` exists 5 times on the post but only twice as an image. You'd need to track all of the contexts to determine when a url displays as an image and when it doesn't. Once you've figured that out then you can just split it out by domain.

While its possible to do this with SQL I wouldn't, and I like SQL. Instead you can take the [datadumps](http://www.clearbits.net/creators/146-stack-exchange-data-dump) and parse the post bodies.

Comment: On a totally unrelated sidenote; your display name is too long for the `post-signature` and r gets cut-off!